# Datagrid EditItemTemplate button event not firing

Tags: c#, dynamic, datagrid, linkbutton, edititemtemplate

I am dynamically creating an Item template in a Gridview.

```
TemplateColumn BtnTmpField = new TemplateColumn(); 
BtnTmpField.ItemTemplate = new DynamicallyTemplatedGridViewHandler(ListItemType.Item, "Edit", "Button");  
BtnTmpField.HeaderTemplate = new DynamicallyTemplatedGridViewHandler(ListItemType.Header, "Edit", "Command");  
BtnTmpField.EditItemTemplate = new DynamicallyTemplatedGridViewHandler(ListItemType.EditItem, "Update", "Button"); dgdefault.Columns.Add(BtnTmpField);

public void InstantiateIn(System.Web.UI.Control Container) 
{ 
    switch (ItemType) 
    { 
        case ListItemType.Header: Literal header_ltrl = new Literal(); 
        header_ltrl.Text = "" + FieldName + ""; 
        Container.Controls.Add(header_ltrl); 
        break; 
        case ListItemType.Item: 
        switch (InfoType) 
        { 
             case "Button": 
             LinkButton edit_button = new LinkButton(); 
             edit_button.ID = "edit_button"; 
             edit_button.Text = "Edit"; 
             edit_button.CommandName = "Edit"; 
             Container.Controls.Add(edit_button); 
             break; 
        }
        break;
        case ListItemType.EditItem: 
             if (InfoType == "Button") 
             { 
             LinkButton update_button = new LinkButton(); 
             update_button.ID = "update_button"; 
             update_button.CommandName = "Update"; 
             update_button.Text = "Update  "; 
             LinkButton cancel_button = new LinkButton(); 
             cancel_button.ID = "cancel_button"; 
             cancel_button.CommandName = "Cancel"; 
             cancel_button.Text = "Cancel"; 
             Container.Controls.Add(update_button); 
             Container.Controls.Add(cancel_button);
            }                 
            break;
      }     
}
```

When I select the "Edit" button the "Update" and "Cancel" buttons show up with the selected row editable. The ItemCommand event of the DataGrid fires correctly when "Edit" is clicked. When I click the "Update" or "Cancel" buttons nothing fires. The ItemCommand doesn't fire, and neither does the UpdateCommand or CancelCommand when I explicitly put the onUpdateCommand or onCancelCommand in the ascx page. I can't figure out why nothing is firing when the buttons in the EditItemTemplate is clicked. Also Everything is being loaded on every page_init postback. Any tips would be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. I basically created an item template, and added 3 separate buttons without using the edititem. In the data grid itemdatabound function, I just hide and show the buttons that need to be shown.

Answer (score 0):

Are you rebinding the events in the grid's PreRender?

Comment: Yeah it calls the bind event in the page_init event.

Comment: In my experience you have to bind events twice in Asp.Net.  Once before you process events and again so that they are available on the page.  So, once yes on the init, and again on PreRender.

Comment: The problem is that after I click the "Cancel" button, the "Edit" Button shows back up like it should. I then click on the "Edit" button and the ItemCommand is fired again. For some reason only on the Edit Item does the ItemCommand not fire.

Comment: I did try the PreRender event, and it was still doing the same thing.

Comment: Sorry, for some reason I was thinking event processing not command processing.  Do you have a OnRowEditing event for your grid, and then assign `grid.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;` in it?  You probably do, since it works the first time.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue today.  I noticed that it was calling the "Header" template for edit items.  not sure why, but add the following just before "switch":

```
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("Template: {0}",ItemType.ToString()));
```

if you're testing with a small-ish number of records, you should be able to see that it calls the "header" item type when you attempt to edit the record.

I'd be curious to know if you're experiencing the same thing.